# Application without the `apply` method?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I noticed the following code in `org.scalacheck.Properties` file:

```
  /** Used for specifying properties. Usage:
   *  {{{
   *  property("myProp") = ...
   *  }}}
   */
  class PropertySpecifier() {
    def update(propName: String, p: Prop) = props += ((name+"."+propName, p))
  }

  lazy val property = new PropertySpecifier()
```

I'm not sure what is happening when `property("myProp") = ...` is invoked. There is no `apply` method in the class `PropertySpecifier`. So, what is being called here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may notice that the usage does not only show application but rather something else, the `=` sign. By having your class implement an `update` method you can let the compiler how the *state* of this class can be updated and allowing the `property("myProp") =` syntax.

You can find the same behavior on `Array`s, where `apply` performs read access and `update` write access.

Here is a small example you can use to understand this:

```
final class Box[A](private[this] var item: A) {

  def apply(): A =
    item

  def update(newItem: A): Unit =
    item = newItem

}

val box = new Box(42)
println(box()) // prints 42
box() = 47 // updates box contents
println(box()) // prints 47
```